# MSSQL - Grouping Results using MAX()

Tags: sql, sql-server, max

I have this dataset;

```
dID Num 
11 3
11 4
11 5
13 9
13 11
45 3
45 8
99 44
99 78
99 53
```

I want it to look like this.

```
dID Num 
11 5
13 11
45 8
99 78
```

List all ID's and only show those ID's where the 'Num' is the Largest number for that group of ID's

my attempt here doesnt quite work out.
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1a47f/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost get it right, you just grouped by the wrong column:

```
select dID,
       MAX(num) from data
group by dID
```

See it here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1a47f/3

Answer (score 2):

You seem to just want an aggregation query:

```
select dId, max(num) as num
from data t
group by dId;
```

You need to aggregate by the first column, not the argument to the aggregation function.

If you have oversimplified the problem, and want other columns as well, then use `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, row_number() over (order by num desc) as seqnum
      from data t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```